Problem related to divisibility rules and digits
How do you prove that a 100-digit number that contains one hundred 0's, one hundred 1's, and one hundred 2's as its digits in a random order is not a perfect square? What about two hundred 0's, 1's, and 2's?

if it has one hundred o's and a hundred 1's and a hundred 2's, then it cannot be a one hundred digit number. It must be at least a three hundred digit number>

A square can’t be a multiple of $3$ unless it’s a multiple of $9$

Isn't that explanation only for cubes?

Recall the divisibility rules for 3 and 9:

A number is divisible by 3 iff the sum of its digits is a multiple of 3.
A number is divisible by 9 iff the sum of its digits is a multiple of 9.

You're given that a number has a digit sum of 300, which is divisible by 3, but not by 9.  But this is impossible for a square number.

Why is this impossible for a square number? Sorry if I sound dumb, I'm not used to this topic.

@Aarushi How could a square that's divisible by 3 not be divisible by 9?

@AarushidaGreat: If an integer $r$ is divisible by 3, then $r^2$ is divisible by $3^2 = 9$.  If $r$ is not divisible by 3, then $r^2$ isn't divisible by 3 either.
